# ASP.NET MVC 5 Model in View issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Quick question... I have a project that I load a base model into my layout page. On each of my other models I am able to reference this `BasePage` model which works fine. However, if I create a view which lists a different model I get a compilation error...

To more clearly explain, I make a call to a view which details a list of class enrollments for a user. This model is a `IEnumerable<Enrollment>`. The details view works just fine for each enrollment, but when I try to get the full list, I get a compilation error that tells me that the dictionary requires a model type of `BasePage`.

Any clarity on this would be great!

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm pretty new to .NET... mostly a background in PHP.

BasePage Model -

```
public abstract class BasePage
{

    public BasePage()
    {
        public string prop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Enrollment Model -

```
public class Enrollment : BasePage
{
    #region modelsettings

    private static PageDisplayItem PAGE_DISPLAYITEM = new PageDisplayItem()
    {
        PageNavigationType = PageNavigationType.FullNavigation,
        HasSideNavigation = true,
        HasPageControl = true,
        HasTableHeader = true,
        HasPageHeader = true,
        IsBackgroundDark = false,
        IsContentTransparent = false
    };

    #endregion

    public Enrollment()
    {
        this.SetPageDisplay(this, PAGE_DISPLAYITEM);
    }

    public Enrollment(bool isInitialize, string entityGUID = "")
    {
        //  common props
        var session = Helper.GetSession();
        var planRepo = new PlanRepository();
        var cmnRepo = new CommonRepository();


        //  set guid
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityGUID))
        {
            var entityRepo = new EntityRepository();
            this.EntityItem = entityRepo.ReturnEntityOrUserItem(this.PageLanguageType, entityGUID);

            if (this.EntityItem.EntityID == 0)
            {
                this.EntityItem = new EntityItem()
                {
                    EntityGUID = session.SessionUserItem.UserGUID,
                    EntityName = session.SessionUserItem.UserFullName,
                    EntityID = session.SessionUserItem.UserID,
                    EntityType = EntityType.User
                };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.EntityItem = new EntityItem()
            {
                EntityGUID = session.SessionUserItem.UserGUID,
                EntityName = session.SessionUserItem.UserFullName,
                EntityID = session.SessionUserItem.UserID,
                EntityType = EntityType.User
            };
        }



        //  init
        if (isInitialize)
        {
            //  page
            this.SetPageDisplay(this, PAGE_DISPLAYITEM);


        }
    }

    #region modelprops

    // BasePage properties
    public EntityItem EntityItem { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentPeriod { get; set; }
    public PeriodItem DisplayPeriod { get; set; }
    public List<PeriodItem> PeriodList { get; set; }

    // Enrollment properties
    public string Id { get; set; }


    #endregion
}
```

Here is the _Layout.cshtml page... I cut out the guts for brevity's sake:

```
@model BasePage

@{
    var m = @Model;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@m.PageTabTitle @m.PageTabTitleExtension</title>
```

Here is the User model that I have created to show the details of the User model which works fine referencing the BasePage Model from the User model:

```
public class User : BasePage
{

    #region modelsettings

    private static PageDisplayItem PAGE_DISPLAYITEM = new PageDisplayItem()
    {
        PageNavigationType = PageNavigationType.FullNavigation,
        HasSideNavigation = true,
        HasPageControl = true,
        HasTableHeader = true,
        HasPageHeader = true,
        IsBackgroundDark = false,
        IsContentTransparent = false
    };

    #endregion

    public User()
    {
        this.SetPageDisplay(this, PAGE_DISPLAYITEM);
    }

    public User(bool isInitialize, string entityGUID = "")
    {
        //  common props
        var session = Helper.GetSession();
        var planRepo = new PlanRepository();
        var cmnRepo = new CommonRepository();


        //  set guid
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityGUID))
        {
            var entityRepo = new EntityRepository();
            this.EntityItem = entityRepo.ReturnEntityOrUserItem(this.PageLanguageType, entityGUID);

            if (this.EntityItem.EntityID == 0)
            {
                this.EntityItem = new EntityItem()
                {
                    EntityGUID = session.SessionUserItem.UserGUID,
                    EntityName = session.SessionUserItem.UserFullName,
                    EntityID = session.SessionUserItem.UserID,
                    EntityType = EntityType.User
                };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.EntityItem = new EntityItem()
            {
                EntityGUID = session.SessionUserItem.UserGUID,
                EntityName = session.SessionUserItem.UserFullName,
                EntityID = session.SessionUserItem.UserID,
                EntityType = EntityType.User
            };
        }



        //  init
        if (isInitialize)
        {
            //  page
            this.SetPageDisplay(this, PAGE_DISPLAYITEM);


        }
    }


#region modelprops

    // BasePage props
    public EntityItem EntityItem { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentPeriod { get; set; }
    public PeriodItem DisplayPeriod { get; set; }
    public List<PeriodItem> PeriodList { get; set; }

    // User props
    public string Id { get; set; }

#endregion


}
```

This is the .cshtml page for User details that works fine with the _Layout.cshtml being used:

```
@model FD.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Profile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BaseLayout.cshtml";
    var m = Model;
}
```

And finally, here is the .cshtml for the Enrollment list that shows the user's classes that they're currently enrolled in. For some reason, when I used the IEnumerable type it explodes during compilation:

```
@model IEnumerable<FD.Models.Enrollment>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
// Again, I cut out the rest for the sake of brevity.
```

Here is the compilation error I get in the browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FD.Models.Enrollment]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'FD.WWW.Models.BasePage'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item
>   passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FD.Models.Enrollment]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'FD.WWW.Models.BasePage'.

Comment: Are you able to provide any code samples to further explain your issue?

Comment: You are going have to show an example in code with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your _Layout page is also being referenced by the other pages then the problem is that you are already defining a  model in _Layout of type `BasePage` then in your Enrollment page you changing it to `IEnumerable<FD.Models.Enrollment>` which will cause a problem as its expecting a model derived from `BasePage` as declared in _Layout which will take precedence when you pass the Model from the Controller to the View. While `FD.Models.Enrollment` derives from `BasePage`, `IEnumerable<FD.Models.Enrollment>` does not.

The reason the User page still works is because its model `FD.Models.User` derives from `FD.WWW.Models.BasePage`.

You can either

1. remove the `BasePage` model from the _Layout.cshtml
2. or change layout used by the enrollment page to use one that does not have the `BasePage` as it model.

   ```html
   @{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SomeOtherLayout.cshtml";}
   @model IEnumerable<FD.Models.Enrollment>

   <p>
       @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
   </p>
   <table class="table">
   ```